# Linear Mixed Effects Model

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, glmm, offset

I have data with some of the following columns: Site (categorical, 1-4), Species (Categorical, 1-21), Damage (continuous), and Age (categorical, 0-6). Age represents the visits to each site where I recorded elephant damage on the species of plants. So an Age of 0 represents old damage, and Ages 1-6 represent any new damage observed. I am looking to run a GLMM with poisson distribution to predict Damage. My question is whether Age is controlled for via something along the lines of "y~x+(1|Age)" or whether in this case I need to offset my data. I am not well versed with GLMMs so any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the gist of how you'd set up a mixed effects model (or rather, that's the right pattern for how you'd write it using most mixed model libraries in R).

As for whether that's conceptually the right model, it depends on how you're defining age. The term (1|Age) models Age category-specific intercept effects. Random effects are typically defined so that each individual group's random effect follows a Standard Normal distribution, and the sum of all random effect estimates is zero (some groups are above average, some are below average).

Comment: Cheers for the response!